# Why was Google Maps built using canvas? If it was built today, would it have rather used react/angular? Why (not)?

Tags: angularjs, html5, canvas, react, google-maps

Google Maps' frontend is almost completely dependent on canvas.

Given that it was initially developed a long time ago, is it still the best approach to take to build such a UI? If not, what is and why?

Comment: Why would you need react or angular for something like google maps?! Besides of adding lots of KBs, making it slower and more complex, what exactly would be the point? ...if it's a nail, use a hammer, otherwise, don't.

Comment: Conversely, why would you use canvas for an ordinary forms application?  Use the proper tool for the job.

Answer (score 4):

Any map based application will use Canvas, SVG or WebGL for actually drawing the map and it is orthogonal to using Angular or even page being SPA at all. Look at frameworks like https://openlayers.org/ and http://leafletjs.com/ to have better idea which parts of google-maps are actually Canvas dependent.